# Turtlebot rviz Camera & Point Cloud2 topics not available to choose

Tags: rviz, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following "Visualizing Turtlebot Kinect Data" tutorial, can add Camera and Point Cloud 2 (Yellow background), but Image Topic depth or rgb choices are not listed. Image window is black. Dashboard Diagnostic & Breaker 0 so Kinect is powered on-blinking green light and red laser is on.

Workstation roswtf gives this:

```
Found 16 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/robot_state_publisher] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/master_sync_Herschel_15710_1025976273] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/diagnostic_aggregator] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/kinect_laser_narrow] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rviz_1335325216462728209] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/turtlebot_dashboard_3012_1335324855229] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/openni_manager] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/robot_pose_ekf] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/openni_camera] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/kinect_laser] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/pointcloud_throttle] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/turtlebot_laptop_battery] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/turtlebot_node] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/app_manager] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/turtlebot_dashboard_cpp_1335324855385011408] raised an error:
```

What should I check or edit?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32525/turtlebot-rviz-camera-&-point-cloud2-topics-not-available-to-choose/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was fixed after discovering there appears to have been a power problem with my iCreate base. Powering the Kinect with its provided AC supply (rather than the Turtlebot Gyro and Power Adapter) and manually running roscore and kinect.launch result in good Camera and PointCloud 2 operation.

---

Originally posted by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) with karma: 141 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0